# How close a sample is to the Normal distribution ( Berry-Esseen Theorem)

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-inequalities

**My question is how can I use the Berry-Esseen Theorem to know how close to the Gaussian distribution is $L$**, where

**$$L=nLn(2)+Ln(r_1)+Ln(r_2)...Ln(r_n).$$**

$r_i \geq 0$ is a i.i.d. random variable from the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

The mean and variance for $Ln(r_1)$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
  \mathbb{E}[Ln(r_1)]&=&-\frac{\gamma}{2},\\
   \mathbb{E}[(Ln(r_1)-\mathbb{E}[Ln(r_1)])^2]&=&\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[Ln(r_1)]=\frac{\pi^2}{24},\\
\end{eqnarray}

Where $\gamma=0.57721$.

**Berry-Esseen Theorem:** Let $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ be real i.i.d. random variables satisfying

\begin{eqnarray*}
   \mathbb{E}[Z_i]&=&v,\\
   \mathbb{E}[(Z_i-v)^2]&=&\sigma^2>0,\\
   \mathbb{E}[|Z_i-v|^3]&=&\rho<\infty
\end{eqnarray*}

Then let 
\begin{equation*}
    Z:=Z_1+\ldots+Z_n,
\end{equation*}

and let $W \thicksim \mathcal{N}(vn,\sigma^2n)_\mathbb{R}$ be a real gaussian with mean $vn$ and variance $\sigma^2n$. Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,\begin{equation*}
    |Pr[Z\leq x]- Pr[W \leq x]\leq \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}},
\end{equation*}

where $C$ is some universal constant.